# Show popup with image on-click

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, image, razor

I have an MVC 5 application that contains a BookList. In the razor view a show the cover of each book by sending the ISBN to Amazon:

```
<img id="@item._id" class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="max-width: 110px" src=@string.Format("http://images.amazon.com/images/P/{0}.01.mzzzzzzz", @item.isbn)>
```

These images are off course in a `foreach` loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {...}
```

What I want to do is, using jquery, show an enlarged version of the cover in a popup. For this I've been following a solution I found somewhere online. In order for the on-click to work, I've used the class that I assigned to the image:

```
$(".img").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        deselect();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(".pop").slideFadeToggle(function () {
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

In this function a css class is applied or removed that will show or hide a div that contains the enlarged image:

```
<div class="messagepop pop">
    <img id="@item._id" class="img" src=@string.Format("http://images.amazon.com/images/P/{0}", @item.isbn)>
</div>
```

The problem I'm facing is that clicking on the image, the class is applied to all images with the `.img` in the list and all the enlarged covers are shown. I need to somehow identify the specific image that was clicked. I thought that would be achieved by $(this), but apparently not.

Comment: can you give more html code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having right now is because $(this) refers to all elements that have the class .img. Thus, you are not targeting the element that calls the click event.

Try the following code and let me know if it works.

```
$(".img").click(function (evt) {
    var clicked = evt.target.id;
    if ( $('#' + clicked).hasClass("selected") ) {
       deselect();
    } else {
       $('#' + clicked).addClass("selected");
       $('.pop #' + clicked).parent().slideFadeToggle();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. You put me on the right track. I did still have a problem with `$(".pop").slideFadeToggle(function () {});` still acting on all the div's with the class pop. What I did was give the div an id of `id=@string.Format("Pop{0}", item._id)` and then used this:  `$("#Pop" + clicked).slideFadeToggle(function () { });`

Comment: I have edit the answer. You will need to use the parent() function to traverse one up to find the .pop element. Cheers!

Comment: Problem is, the image that is clicked is not inside of the div with .pop - there are 2 images. The smaller one that is clicked and the bigger one in the div that is displayed

Comment: I have edited the answer again. Let me know if it works.